# QUnit Async Tests with setup And teardown

Tags: asynchronous, installation, qunit, teardown

I need a little help understanding QUnit internas. 
I read its source from time to time, but i'm still writing weird test when it comes to asynchronous tests.
I understand the concept of asynchronous tests, and the stop() and start() methods (and why they are needed), but when i combine them with setup and teardown i get a lot of weired situations.

Here is my Testcode:

```
use(['Psc.Exception','Psc.Code'], function () {
  module("async", {
    setup: function () {
      console.log('setup');
    }, teardown: function () {
      console.log('teardown');
    }
  });

  asyncTest("test1", function () {
    expect(0);

    console.log('test1');
    start();
  });

  asyncTest("test2", function () {
    expect(0);

     console.log('test2');
     start();
  });

  asyncTest("test3", function () {
    expect(0);

    console.log('test3');
    start();
  });

  asyncTest("test4", function () {
    expect(0);

    console.log('test4');
    start();
  });

  asyncTest("test5", function () {
    expect(0);

    console.log('test5');
    start();
  });
});
```

Allthough these are asynchron tests, i thought i would get something like this in the console:

```
setup
test1
teardown
setup
test2
teardown
setup
test3
teardown
...
```

because i thought qunit would call setup and teardown around the test bodys?

but I get everything mixed up, from request to request in another way shuffled.

```
setup
test1
teardown
setup
setup
setup
setup
test5
teardown 
test4
teardown
test3
teardown
test2
teardown
```

is someone able to explain it step by step?

Comment: okay, so I stopped trying to understand the issue. I just came to the solution that the setup function is useless if this is called from qunit this way. Because "global" test variables will always be overriden. So i started to include my setup functions into the test itself, which works really well

Comment: Max Cantor believes you may have found a bug in QUnit.  You can find his bug report and fix for this on GitHub: https://github.com/jquery/qunit/pull/320

Comment: There's still something buggy about setup/teardown with `asyncTest` functions; even with the "fix". In my tests, it seems better but it eventually hiccups and makes multiple calls to setup in succession. Perhaps, if I debugged the qunit code, I'd get a better understanding of the issue but I just don't feel like I should have to do that. Instead, as @P.scheit mentioned, I think I'll be pitching my dependencies on modular setup/teardown. Possibly QUnit altogether...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a documented issue:

http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.config/

its is recommended to set QUnit.config.autostart to false, when loading tests asynchronously. This is my case because "use" is doing it asynchronously.

The head looks like this:

```
QUnit.config.autostart = false;
use(['Psc.Exception','Psc.Code'], function () {

  QUnit.start();
  module("async", {
```

So its basically like doing stop() and start() but for loading the tests itself. I tested it and the teardown / setup / test now get correctly executed in the right order

Comment: I'm doing this and the process just closes without running any tests:
```JavaScript

QUnit.config.autostart = false;

var tests = require("./tests.js");
tests.setup().then(() => {
  console.log("start...");
  QUnit.start();
});
```